# It there any way to automatically visualizate JavaScript code tree?

Tags: javascript, c#, algorithm, code-generation

I want to rewrite pretty complex application from JavaScript to C#. I have not created it and it is really complicated for me to find functions and convert them to C#. I was thinking about it and I think that creating some sort of "code tree" would help me, so I will know where to start.

The tree should show me how are the functions called, so I can determine what to rewrite first.

[image: Image representation]
As you can see on example image that would be generated, I would start with `finalFunc` and `chickenFunc` since there are no more functions to move, then continue with `someOtherFunc` and `getChickenTypes`...

Is there any way to do it? If not have you got any tips to start rewriting a code that you have never seen before?

Comment: If it is only JavaScript, you can try FlowMaker for VSCode: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=speks.flowmaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some of these projects:

- https://github.com/sverweij/dependency-cruiser
- https://github.com/pahen/madge

Comment: Not exactly the thing I wanted, because it doesn´t show you the functions graph, BUT it is really great and helpful. Gonna wait if someone comes with something better and if not, this is accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

If it is only JavaScript, you can try FlowMaker for VSCode:

http://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=speks.flowmaker